# Make `php` recognized as a command in terminal

Tags: php, symbolic-link, mint

I have `XAMPP` installed and my PHP is:

`/opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8`

Every time I need to execute a PHP file I need to do this:

`/opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8 testando.php`

Is there another way to execute it besides using symbolic link?

I did this on `/etc/init.d/`:

`sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8 php`

Why when I need to run PHP  I have to do this `./php` instead of just `php`?

And is there a way to do this without the `./`? Like it was installed via `apt-get`?

Comment: include the output of `echo $PATH` please

Comment: Questions that are about Linux Mint (as you said is what you're running, in [a comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/146903/make-php-recognized-as-a-command-in-terminal#comment177104_146906) to [Lord of Time](http://askubuntu.com/users/10616/lord-of-time)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/146906/22949)) and not about Ubuntu [are off-topic](http://$SITEURL$/faq#questions). You should instead ask this somewhere Linux Mint is supported, like the [Linux Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/) or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a symlink in `/usr/bin` to the PHP binary/executable file.

`sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8 /usr/bin/php` should create a symlink to the executable that exists within /usr/bin, and should allow you to call 'php' from the command line without making an /etc/init.d/ entry.

Comment: That worked but can you explain what is the difference between creating symlink on each folder?

Comment: The way that executable names get run in Bash (or ZSH, or others) is based upon there being either a link or an executable in a folder that is specified in `$PATH` (btw, please add that to your question's content, see comment to the question). When such executables do not exist in a folder specified in `$PATH`, you have to use the entire path to the executable to work. By adding that sym link to /usr/bin, the system then recognizes `php` alone as a command/program.  When *in* the program's folder, though, `./progname`: `./` = currentdir, `progname` = program/executable; Run progname from here.

Comment: how do I `echo $PATH` tried it on terminal and creating a file but it gave me this: `Notice: Undefined variable: PATH`

Comment: hmm, that's odd.  is this Ubuntu or some other distro?

Comment: I'm using Mint.

Comment: ah, well that's different. Let me (for future reference) point you to the FAQ: `This is not the right place for: Linux Mint, Backtrack, and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).` Ask on U&L in future given that Mint isnt supported here. MODS: Do not move this from Ask Ubuntu please, it does have relevance here even though the OS being used is Mint (this is common in non-apt installed software in all debian distros, so it does have relevence to Ubuntu).

Comment: $PATH points to where executables are, so the lack of a $PATH doesn't really mean much (since /bin and /usr/bin are both defaults for binaries).

Comment: This is because of the file system hierarchy standard which describes where resources and executables have to be placed in the file system. Instead of `/usr/bin` recommended locations are `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin` .

Comment: @LiveWireBT true, but without `$PATH` it won't be identified in those locations.  in ubuntu, the php package installs to /bin, but they're using Mint (Ubuntu 12.04 ships with PHP 5.3.8)

Comment: I can not find the bin directory in etc/php/php7.4 nor others. Dont understand where to find the binaries.